# need Url to download MsDeploy packages

Tags: paas

we need below MsDeploy packages to execute ARM template.

1. disablePrefetchCachingMsDeployPackageUrl
2. dataExchangeFrameworkMsDeployPackageUrl
3. dataExchangeFrameworkSitecoreProviderMsDeployPackageUrl

could anyone please help us from where we can download these packages.

extenstion of these packags is "scwdp.zip".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

disablePrefetchCachingMsDeployPackageUrl:
https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/releases/download/v2.0.1/DisablePrefetchCache.scwdp.zip

For the dataexchangeframework packages: you need to create them yourself based on the iaas packages you can download from sitecore. You can do this with powershell by using the Sitecore Azure Toolkit.

Use this command:

```
Import-Module "C:\Software\Azure Toolkit\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.0.0 rev.171010\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll" -Verbose 
$wdpPath = ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path $Origin -Destination $Destination -Force
```

$origin is path to normal package. e.g. $Origin ="c:\packages\dataexchange.zip"
$destination is the folder to put the new scwpd in. e.g. $destination="c:\packages\converted"

Comment: I updated my concern in above answer because it was not taking that much content in comment. please suggest where to put it if approver reject it.

Comment: While Executing the CMD we are getting the following issue
ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage : The term 'ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,

We are not able to understand the $Origin ="c:\packages\dataexchange.zip" and $destination="c:\packages\converted"